# Graphql Apollo setting cookies is dont working

Tags: cookies, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to set cookies in apollo client.
I'm setting the response cookie which works fine, also working on graphql playground with setting "request.credentials": "same-origin", or "include" and it stores cookies successfully.
My problem starts when I'm trying to store cookies from FE app (React, Apollo client). When i put the credentials: "same-origin" the app is working but the cookies are not saved. And when i use "include" the queries are cors blocked.

FRONTEND

```
const RouterComponent: FC = () => {
  const cache = useMemo(() => {
    return new InMemoryCache();
  }, []);

  const client = useMemo(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') || 'token';
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
      },
    });

    const link = from([
      httpLink,
      createUploadLink({
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
      }),
    ]);
    return new ApolloClient({
      link,
      cache,
      typeDefs,
    });
  }, [cache]);

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage} />;
        <Route exact path="/:category" component={Category} />;
      </Switch>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};
```

---

QUERY

```
games: (_: any, args: any, {req, res}: any) => {
        const refresh_token = sign({userId: "123"}, "secret", {expiresIn: "7d"})
        const access_token = sign({userId: "123"}, "secret", {expiresIn: "15min"})

        res.cookie('refresh-token', refresh_token, {expire: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7}) // 7 days
        res.cookie('access-token', access_token, {expire: 60 * 15}) // 15 mins

        return Game.find()
      }
```

SERVER.TS

```
const { ApolloServer } = require( 'apollo-server-express');
const {typeDefs} = require( './typeDefs');
const {resolvers} = require( './resolvers');
const express = require( 'express');
const cors = require( 'cors');
const path = require( 'path');
const bodyParser = require( 'body-parser');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const MONGO_CONNECTION = ""

const app = express();

export default (async function () {
  try {
    
    await mongoose.connect(MONGO_CONNECTION, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true})

    const server = new ApolloServer({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers,
      context: ({ req, res }: any) => {
        return {
          req, 
          res
        };
      },
    });

    const corsConfig = {
      origin: '*',
      credentials: true,
      allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    };

    dotenv.config();
    app.use(function (req: any, res: any, next: any) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
  });
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));

    const dir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'images');
    app.use(express.static(dir));
    app.use(express.static('public'))
    app.use(express.static('files'))
    
    server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsConfig });
    app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
      console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
    )
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

thank you for any help

Comment: `includes`, origin != * ??

Comment: if i put there localhost url same result